# Start / Stop Motor Run with Button State Change

Tags: servo, button

I'm trying to understand Arduino with push buttons. But I can't get the test project I'm working on to work as how I want it to do.

Basically what I'm trying to do with the codes below is to make the push button either start or stop the servo motor. But so far, I couldn't get it to work. I'm also wondering why the servo motor won't run on loop? I tried several approach, but I couldn't get it working.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

By the way, I'm a beginner.

```
#include <Servo.h> //Servo Library.

int servoPin = 3; //Servo to Pin 2.
int led = 4; // LED to Pin 4.
int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;

Servo ServoOne; //Servo object created.

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ServoOne.attach(servoPin);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(2);
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    servoRun();
  }
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}

void servoRun() {
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      Serial.println("Running.");
      ServoOne.write(0); //Servo resets to 0 degrees.
      digitalWrite(led, LOW); //LED turns on.
      delay (1000);
      ServoOne.write(90); //Servo turns to 90 degrees.
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH); //LED turns on.
      delay (1000);
      ServoOne.write(180); //Servo turns to 180 degrees.
      digitalWrite(led, LOW); //LED turns on.
      delay (1000);
      ServoOne.write(90); //Servo turns to 90 degrees.
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH); //LED turns on.
      delay (1000);
      ServoOne.write(0); //Servo resets to 0 degrees.
      digitalWrite(led, LOW); //LED turns on.
    } else {
      Serial.println("Off.");
      ServoOne.write(0);
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
I tried this new approach, but I can't get the button state change saved.

```
#include <Servo.h> //Servo Library.

//Constant.
const int pswitch = 2; //Switch to Pin 2.

//Variables.
int servoPin = 3; //Servo to Pin 3.
int led = 4; //LED to Pin 4.
int newState; //Current switch state.
int oldState = LOW; //Previous switch state.

Servo ServoOne; //Servo object created.

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ServoOne.attach(servoPin);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pswitch, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  newState = digitalRead(pswitch);

  if (oldState == LOW && newState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("ON and running.");
    ServoOne.write(90);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    ServoOne.write(0);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    ServoOne.write(90);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    ServoOne.write(180);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    ServoOne.write(90);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
  } else {
    Serial.println("OFF.");
    delay(1000);
  }
  oldState = newState;
}
```

Comment: write a simple sketch that turn the motor on ... does the motor run?

Comment: what is the purpose of the first `if` statement in `servoRun()`?

Comment: So what I want it to do is to keep the servo running  from 0, 90, 180, 90 and back to 0 on loop. The first if checks the state of the button. If it's pressed, it should supposed to 0 degrees and turn the LED off.

Comment: Basically I wanted to create a toggle switch button using one button. Is it possible? To toggle the servo to turn on and turn off? If it's toggled on, it will continue doing the 0, 90, 180, 90, 0 on loop, and if it's toggled off, it will stop. And if it's toggled on again, it will continue doing its job from where it stopped?

Comment: So, you want one button press to start the motor and keep it turning until the next button press? As far as I can see, one button press will now start the motor, will do a full revolution and then stop. Pressing the button again will start the motor again due to the button bouncing (or it may do nothing if the button is debounced externally). Correct?

Comment: @StarCat -- Yes that's correct. Actually I want the motor to perform a different job (in this sample, I just want it to stop rotating for the sake of simplicity) when the button is pressed. But I can't get the button state change saved.

Comment: @StarCat, I edited the post to show you my current codes. I can't get the state change saved to "newState". How do I do that? Is it even possible?  

Like for a simple example, on press, it will serial print "ON", and when pressed again it will print "OFF".

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the old state saved?  That's what the last line of loop does.  Or do you mean that there is some behavior that makes you think that's what's happening?

Comment: The way you have it written right now, it will detect a button is pressed, that satisfies the if statement.  Then it will follow the lines in that if block one after the other.  So first it prints, lights the led, moves to 90 degrees, sticks it's head in the sand for one second then goes to 0 degrees turn off the led stick head in sand for another full second, and on and on.  Finally when it gets to the end of all of that the loop repeats and it finally gets to check the button again.  So there's no way the button can stop it mid way because the button can't be checked in there.

Comment: @Delta_G -- Sorry for the confusion. Basically what I want the button to do is to make it perform another job. But I think my code is wrong, because it doesn't transfer the state change from newState to oldState so it can compare. So to explain it simpler, how can I make it (let's say) print ON on the first press of a button, and then print OFF on the second press? Like a toggle on and off switch?

Comment: @Delta_G or rather with a press of a button, it will rotate the servo to 180 or 0. Like on first press, it will rotate to 180 and hold its angle until pressed again -- which will rotate it back to 0 degrees.

Comment: Yeah.  I understood what you wanted.  I was explaining why it works now the way it does.   You’re wrong in thinking that you’re not assigning the value of the old state.  That’s what the last line in loop does.   That’s happening.  Get it out of your mind that this is the problem. It’s not.  The problem is that once the button is pressed your code does the entire movement before it checks the button again.  You have blocking code.  You need a non-blocking state machine.  Google that.

Comment: @Delta_G took me a while to figure out what's causing the problem. Turns out it was the delay. I didn't know it stops everything. Finally got it working using millis and adding another variable to check the value of the button. Button works instantaneously as I want it to be. Thanks!

Comment: Execution always runs one line at a time.  No line of code can ever run until the line before it gets executed.  Well that’s not entirely true but for our purposes it’s close enough.  It’s not just delay.  Any command that takes a long time to run is an issue.